# Java GRPC spawns to many new threads (Minecraft Spigot Plugin)

Tags: java, minecraft, grpc-java

I'm writing a Spigot plugin that Sends and Receives Messages via GRPC.
My problem is that after a view hours the server Crashes because the process can't open more file hanldes for new threads.
From looking at some thread dumps it seems that GRPC is spawning multiple threads per Second without ever Closing them.
The Code im using to receive the message stream looks like the following:

```
public class GRPCMessageReceiver extends BukkitRunnable {

ChatSyncGrpc.ChatSyncBlockingStub chatSync;
LockedQueue lockedQueue = new LockedQueue();
Iterator<ChatMessage> receivingIterator;

public GRPCMessageReceiver(ChatSyncGrpc.ChatSyncBlockingStub chatSync, LockedQueue queue){
    lockedQueue = queue;
    this.chatSync = chatSync;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    if (receivingIterator == null) receivingIterator = chatSync.beginReceive(Empty.newBuilder().build());
    try {
        if (receivingIterator.hasNext()) {
            ChatMessage message = receivingIterator.next();
            lockedQueue.Put(message);
            message.
        }
    } catch (io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException e) {
        receivingIterator = chatSync.beginReceive(Empty.newBuilder().build());
        Bukkit.getLogger().info("Chat Sync Connection Failed created new one!");
    }
}
```

}
All Threads have the same Stack Trace:

```
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
  at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:211)
  at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$ThreadlessExecutor.waitAndDrain(ClientCalls.java:731)
  at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$BlockingResponseStream.waitForNext(ClientCalls.java:622)
  at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$BlockingResponseStream.hasNext(ClientCalls.java:643)
  at HausSheepPlugin.GRPCMessageReceiver.run(GRPCMessageReceiver.java:26)
  at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R2.scheduler.CraftTask.run(CraftTask.java:81)
  at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R2.scheduler.CraftAsyncTask.run(CraftAsyncTask.java:54)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Is this a problem on my side or on GRPCs side?

Comment: It looks like this is a streaming RPC.  Does the stream ever get properly closed from the server?  If not, you'd have a zillion threads all waiting for the end of their streams.

Comment: The system is setup so that the Servercan push messages to the Client instead of the client constantly pulling. So the stream gets only closed by the server when the connection breaks/the server or client shutdown.

Comment: How many RPCs are you running, then?  Is `run()` expected to only happen once, or many times?

Comment: Run is Executed twice a second. the `beginReceive` Method is called the first time `run()` is called and when the `hasNext()` function whrows the `io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException` which means that the connection is faulty. I have already checked that the connection does not get reastablished every `Run()` Execution.

Comment: Can you show how `run()` gets executed?  Where `receivingIterator` is stored?

Comment: `run()` is called by spigot every 10 frames with a frame rate of 30 Ticks. I have Edited the question with the complete java class.

Comment: You seem to be chucking live GRPC connections into a queue and leaving them there. You should probably consume the message and close the connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hasNext()` waits until an element arrives or the stream is closed.

If an element just hasn't arrived yet, it will sit around waiting until another element arrives.  When many calls do that, you get more threads waiting than elements, so threads keep stacking up.

So, more or less: you shouldn't be structuring your receipt of the stream this way.  Either use the async API and a `StreamObserver` -- which seems to match your code's needs anyway -- or have `run()` consume the entire iterator, instead of trying to just consume one element.